# Can I use Interface Builder to inject dependencies across multiple nibs?

Tags: cocoa, dependency-injection, interface-builder

I am used to supplying the dependencies for my objects from the outside. Interface Builder is a tool that helps doing this, but I can’t make it work with multiple nibs. As soon as I break the main nib into more files, I can no longer make connections between objects in different nibs. Using File Owner does not help very much, since it only allows me to pass one single object into a nib.

Example:

[image]

Here A and B are some higher-level objects and C and D some kind of lower-level services. As long as all objects are inside one big nib (first picture), everything is fine. But when I split the nib to separate A and B, I have trouble connecting them to C and D. (Obviously I do not want to create two instances of C and D, I want both A and B talking to the same C and D without using a singleton.)

Is it possible to do this in Interface Builder? How?

Answer (score 2):

The Objects in your .nib correspond to your view layer, right? When unarchived they are owned by your chosen controller, which mediates between your services and your view.

It would be really unconventional to have any kind of lower-level services, or any kind of dependencies at all archived in your .nib file.

Comment: They are not just views, I also have controllers and models in my nibs. It could be that Interface Builder was not designed to be used this way (it’s *Interface* Builder after all), but hooking the whole object graph was so easy I could not resist. The only issue that remains for me is splitting the nibs.

Comment: You are right, Interface Builder was not designed to be used this way. Have you looked at Core Data? Keep your nib files strictly for your views and use Core Data for your model - you will be much happier.

Comment: Does Core Data really fit in here? Note that I am *not* creating some OO database with data using IB, I simply use it to establish the dependencies between my objects. Like `SettingsController` depends on the `SettingsWindow` and the `Settings` model, the `Settings` model depends on some user defaults, and so on.

Comment: Core Data might not be relevant here, but note, CD has nothing (ok, very little) todo with OO databases or ORMs. It just lets you visually hook up your model graph, gives you persistence, undo/redo, and makes it easy to hookup data to your views. Back to your point - trying to archive your whole app structure in a nib might seem like a good idea in the simple case, but as you are finding out, it will be more of a hindrance than a help in every other case. Keep the nib just for your views.

Answer (score 1):

You should use External Objects. In your xib add external object. You can find it in object library. Use it as ordinary object (outlets and so on). Since there's a external object, it will not be created through unarchiving process, you should create yourself. Then you load your nib programmatically:

```
NSArray*    topLevelObjs = nil;
NSDictionary*    proxies = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self forKey:@"AppDelegate"];
NSDictionary*    options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:proxies forKey:UINibExternalObjects];
topLevelObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self options:options];
```

More about nib files: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW24